# What does the Fetch Analysis variable in Whitebox Tools represent?

Tags: qgis, dem, whitebox-gat

I have a DEM of Scotland. I used BreachDepressionsLeastCost to process it. I then derived the Fetch Analysis raster. The problem is that the values, both positive and negative, are very high. The output variables are supposed to represent the ray distance to the next 'obstacle' from a cell in metres. However, the values are in the 100,000s. Clearly this can't be in metres.
Any input on this issue would be most appreciated